# Database and DB provider for hybrid mobile app

Tags: database, sqlite, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am new to hybrid mobile app development. I am coming from web based development background so bit perplexed.

I zeroed down on Apache/Cordova for build/packaging my hybrid mobile app. This app would be hosted on all 3 major stores. After my initial research, I got a good flavor of UI pieces/frameworks e.g. Angular, Bootstrap, etc. One thing where I got so confused is back-end storage, services and provider. In other words,

1. What storage services do i need for storing and pulling data (not offline app data)?
2. Based on storage service how do I decide on provider. Any guidance?
3. Best way for making calls for all my CRUD operations?
4. Do I need any kind of server side operations or client side JS would suffice?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Mobile service to store and pull data, each mobile service comes with database. You can try out the [trial version](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/) to see whether it meets your requirement.

Follow the below steps to add Azure mobile service to your project through Visual Studio:

```
1.) Right click on project node and select Add --> Connected Services.
2.) Sign-in with your Azure account. Click on Create Service to create new mobile service.
3.) Select the newly created mobile service and click Ok.
4.) It will add service.js, which contains Azure mobile service object.
5.) You can use Azure mobile service object to perform CRUD operations like

var CordovaAppClient
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {    
    CordovaAppClient = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(
                    "https://Dummyapp.azure-mobile.net/",
                    "IsBLy-----ScCqDMuCCZqVlF------");
});

function ReadData()
{
    var table = CordovaAppClient.getTable("Item");
    var query = table.where({ complete: true });

    query.read().then(function(items)
    {
        listItems = $.map(items, function (item) {
            alert(item.text);

        });
    });
}

function InsertData()
{   
    var table = CordovaAppClient.getTable("Item");
    var inputTest = $('#txtData').val();

    table.insert({ text: inputTest, complete: false })
            .then(addmessage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insights. Will investigate further on this.

Comment: Does it have OData like features? Or how custom my SQL can be in terms of joins, includes etc. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it supports OData and you can write custom queries with Joins, not sure about Includes. You can find more detail http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started/